# Compatible version of CCBReader with CocosBuilder

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I'm currently using cocos2d iPhone 2.1 and i'm trying to use CCBReader and CocosBuilder to create an application. I've downloaded and using CocosBuilder 3.0 alpha 5 and the latest version of CCBReader from the master branch on git: https://github.com/cocos2d/CCBReader

When using this version of CCBReader it reads it as a CCScene and the layers from CocosBuilder show up on screen but for some reason they do not animate (there should be some animations occurring according to the timeline). I'm thinking it something to do with the versions of these products I'm using? Has anyone else experienced this problem before? Or if anyone could show me what build of CCBReader to use with cocos2d iPhone v2.1 and CocosBuilder 3.0 alpha 5 that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocosBuilder 3.0 alpha 5 has git tag "v3.0-alpha5" (with commit ID: 76499877e8c5f9da04406065506a144dd3cc228e) that matches up with the following related repos:

- CCBReader commit ID: c48260028dc5b2e0de5f76504ad584f017a5accb
- cocos2d-iphone commit ID: b51de15acb37d72719b03314771e4caa04e57a33 (v2.1 rc-2)

One way to find a compatible set of these tools is to checkout a git commit with a given tag like "v3.0-alpha5" in the CocosBuilder repo (https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder.git) and look at its submodules. This repo is using submodules to link to exact versions of CCBReader and cocos2d-iphone repos.

Concerning your real problem, scenes that won't animate, I have experienced that same. Right now, if I create a scene (ccb file) in a new project with CocosBuilder 3.0 alpha 5 containing an animation, the animation won't run when I push the scene using:

```
[director pushScene:[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"Scene.ccbi"]];
```

But, if I create the scene inside an older project file, like the CocosBuilderExample included in the repo, using CocosBuilder 3.0 alpha 5, the published scene (ccbi file) does animate. There might be a problem creating ccb files using a fresh ccbproj file created with version 3.0. Maybe the CocosBuilderExample project works because it's was created in an older version of CocosBuilder like 2.1. But that's a guess.